# Cut The UIView in rectangle shape

Tags: iphone, ios

UIView is placed on the UIImageview. When i touch on the UIView at that point we have to cut the view(width,height is our wish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) touch event:-   for location `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

2) draw CGRect:- use this code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // Drawing code
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150, 150);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 200);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50, 150);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);
     CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
     CGContextFillPath(context); }
```

3) use simple animation for view

Comment: Thank you for giving reply.How to call the drawRect method?

Comment: [self.viewName setNeedsDisplayInRect:];

Comment: If i am doing like that,In NSLog  the output is TouchView[4970] <Error>: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0

Comment: please use the Quartz Core framwork

Comment: Please use graphical change on Main thread

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer

Answer (score 0):

the below method gives a image of the UIView, implement this

```
+ (UIImage*) giveScreentshjotsOfView:(UIView*) view
{
if (view == nil)
    return nil;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```

using this u can get the image, and use accordingly

Comment: Thank you for giving reply.I think it is for screen shot for image.I want to cut the view. If i cut that view,at that time it shows some part of image.

Answer (score 0):

Steps .

1) Get the touch location in `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

2) Make A CGRect there with that touch locations it centre..(make it a Square..equal width and height)
3) Set the view's frame to the CGRect.

4) Animate the change..

And you are done.

Comment: Thank you for giving reply. I have done like that only. But the problem is in drawRect method.So how can i call those method.

Comment: when you set the view's frame to CGrect .. call [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; in the next line

Comment: If i am doing like that,In NSLog  the output is TouchView[4970] <Error>: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0

Comment: update your question with the code of your -(void)touchesEnded method..

Comment: -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];;
//    viewScreen.hidden=YES;
   CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView: [touch view]]; 
    CGRect rectValue=CGRectMake(currentPosition.x,currentPosition.y, 50,50);
    NewView *newInstance=[[NewView alloc]init];
    [newInstance drawRect:rectValue];
    [newInstance release];
}

Comment: - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIRectFill( rect );
    CGRect gapArea = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
    CGRect rectTofill = CGRectIntersection(gapArea, rect );
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    
    UIRectFill( rectTofill );
}

Comment: post it in the question with correct formatting..not here in comment..